# Importing SASS partials from node_modules

Tags: sass, gulp

Trying to build custom workflow with gulp, panini, mustache, sass and one of my problem is including partials from node_modules, here is example from main.scss file:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "settings";
```

How to avoid typing full path to _mixins.scss?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your question is similar to this: [Sass import not crawling node_modules to find appropriate package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511455/sass-import-not-crawling-node-modules-to-find-appropriate-package/41513500#41513500)

You can include paths by passing the includePaths argument to gulp sass. e.g

```
.pipe($.sass({
  includePaths: ['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/', 'another/path']
})
```

Answer (score 17):

You can include `node_modules` in sass pathes:

```
.pipe(sass({
  includePaths: ['node_modules']
})
```

Then you can import library's sass like this:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Or, in case of [material-components-web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-top-app-bar#styles):

```
@import "@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar";
```

This way:

- you don't need to add each lib to path
- the sub-dependencies imports will work seamlessly, e.g. mdc-top-app-bar in MDC example imports "@material/elevation/mixins".

Answer (score 1):

Use [includePaths](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/README.md) or you could resolve NPM modules like this:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "settings";
```

There are some libraries for this [sass-globbing](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-globbing), but I personally don't like this approach, because in CSS matters on import order.

Best practice is IMHO create some file `vendor.scss`;

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bourbon/...";
```

and then import this `vendor.scss`:

```
@import "vendor.scss"

@import "partials/..."
```

Comment: There is a way, check out gulp-sass includePaths

Comment: True, I'm complete forget about it.

Comment: In my case this is not working `File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/functions`. Can you provide a gulpfile.js?

Comment: Hey @muuvmuuv you might need something like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-package-importer. It has been some time since I used SASS last time.

Comment: Yeah, after searching the web a bit I found similar packages but finally I wrote my own (4 lines long). Anyway thanks!

Comment: @muuvmuuv I think `~` is not supposed to be there, `"bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that stumbles here, if you're using `gulp-ruby-sass` instead of `node-sass` you would use

```
loadPath: ['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/']
```

instead of

```
includePaths: ['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/']
```